# Is there a way to send parameters in json format to an installed windows app using java?

Tags: java, spring, windows, api, intellij-idea

I have a Java api project set up on IntelliJ IDEA. I am able to GET and POST simple json data using the api. However, my main goal is to find a way to send Command Line Parameters (in json format) to a windows app installed on my machine using the api. Is there a command in Java or some other way that lets me target an app on my machine to send command line parameters to?

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Greeting getAllUsers(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="buddy") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

This is api controller I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an external OS application from your java then look at classes [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Here is a simple example of how to run Notepad from java:

```
private static void testProcessRunner() {
    try {
        new ProcessBuilder("notepad").start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course here you can run a command with parameters. So in your controller, when you get your parameters for your application, build a command with your params that you want to run and use `ProcessBuilder` to run your command